# Star Schema modeling Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

According to this documentation [Primary key, foreign key, and unique key in Synapse SQL pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-table-constraints), `Azure Synapse` doesn't support `foreign keys`.

Thus, how can I model the `star schema` in `Azure Synapse`? Or is it not necessary on `Azure Synapse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation you have linked:

> Having primary key and/or unique key allows Synapse SQL pool engine to
> generate an optimal execution plan for a query

> After creating a table with primary key or unique constraint in
> Synapse SQL pool, **users need to make sure** all values in those columns
> are unique. A violation of that may cause the query to return inaccurate result.

The take away from the above is that Synapse DB does not support constraints. PK and Unique "constrains" are purely for query performance optimisation and do not actually enforce uniqueness.